# android studio 2022.1.1 unresolved reference Intent and Button kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
package com.example.systemmainframe104

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btnSecondActivity = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnSecondActivity)
        btnSecondActivity.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Button and Intent say unresolved reference

no clue what to try

ive been stuck for a long time and cannot seem how to get the error to disapear and its the last error i have to solve so i can then switch tabs in my android app, now working on android studio 7.0 kotlin 2022.1.1 electric eel patch 2

Comment: Based on the code snippet above, there seems to be some missing imports (for the button and the intent).